# Problem to compare 2 symboles with pinescript Tradingview

Tags: pine-script

I try to compare my actual ticker with another in a new windows.
I try to use syminfo.tickerid but it's don't work.

I just want to plot QQQ/XLE for example but with a script.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What have you tried and what problem do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script",timeframe= "",overlay=false,format=format.price)

ticker      = input.symbol("AAPL")
sec_close   = request.security(ticker,"",close)

actual_close= request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"",close)

plot(sec_close,color=color.orange)

plot(actual_close)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).